# How to create Socket sent data to server in Android?

Tags: java, android, sockets

Implementation of MainActivity.java class

The usage of client class demo from internet . Just create a object of Client class and pass IP and port of server and response TextView.

But when sent data to server, How to code buttonSent?

1.Client.java  This is client class

```
package com.androidsrc.client;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String response = "";
    TextView textResponse;

    Client(String addr, int port,TextView textResponse) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
        this.textResponse=textResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                    1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

            /*
             * notice: inputStream.read() will block if no data return
             */
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        textResponse.setText(response);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

2.MainActivity.java Here is what MainActivity.java looks like, I add new buttonSent who can trigger sent data to server.How to code buttonSent?

```
package com.androidsrc.client;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView response;
    EditText editTextAddress,
    editTextPort;
    Button buttonConnect,
    buttonClear,
    buttonUp;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
        editTextPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.portEditText);
        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
        buttonClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearButton);
        response = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseTextView);
        buttonSent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectSent);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Client myClient = new Client(editTextAddress.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString()), response);
                myClient.execute();
            }
        });
        buttonSent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            //When sent data to server, How to code here??

        });

        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                response.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `Client` ?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the results back from what `Client.execute()` is doing?

Comment: Android client sent data to server

Comment: anybody can help me?